# How to use base class function using derived class object when the same function is overloaded in derived class?

Tags: c++

I created a base class A, with a member function display(). Another class B inheriting A class that is overloading the function display().
Calling this function using the derived class object, the function called was the overloaded display.
I want to call the original inherited function of the base class using the derived class object.

I have tried this approach.

```
B b=B();
b.A::display();
```

Here is the code:

```
class A{
    public:
        void display()
        {
             printf("base class");
        }
};
class B : public A{
    public:
        void display()
        {
             printf("derived class");
        }
};
```

using

```
B b=B();
b.display();
```

The output was derived class;
I want to output base class using object b;

Comment: Is this what you want? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18c82f7f5064038f

Comment: [`b.A::display();`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UfepbdzpSutVSs1b)?